# Appcelerator notification IOS 8 - no sound

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

Im using appcelerator 4.0.0. I have downloaded the code of this appcelerator toturial and tried to add sound to the notification.
http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/09/new-in-sdk-3-4-ios-8-interactive-notifications/

However I cant seem to get the sounds working. The notification settings/permissions on the device are good. I have tested on simulator and real device.

```
var notif = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    date: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5000), // send it in 5 sec
    alertBody: 'This is your message',
    badge: 1,
    sound: 'default',
    userInfo: {"url": "http://www.download.com/resource/asset.json", id:"1"},
    category: "DOWNLOAD_CONTENT"
});
```

Comment: The docs describe the sound parameter as path to a local sound file. Have you tried to put a sound file to your Resources and and link it? Does that work?

Comment: I have tried that and that is also what I would like to achieve in the end. However 'default' should point to the default notification sound. If we were to get this working using the system default sound a custom sound would be a easy next step.

Comment: Have you tried to schedule the notification in future? As far as I remember push notifications will not play any sounds when the app is opened on receival. May be similar with local notifs. So does it work when you schedule the notif in e.g. 10 seconds and close the app till then?

Comment: It does not, please try code from url

Comment: Is your app open when receiving Notification, or Close? To receive sound your app should be in background or, closed state..

Comment: Yes the app is closed, the notification works but not the sound

Answer (score 1):

Wait, there are some misunderstandings in your code.

`Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification` schedule a notification, but if you set `date = new Date(new Date().getTime())`, the app is still in foreground... and when the app is in foreground, no iOS banner is shown = no sound.

So, what you have to do is `date: new Date(Date.now() + 5000)`, and close the app.

Comment: You are right about that, but that doesn't solve the problem. Please also test using the code from the url

Comment: I tried and everything is working fine, the sound is audible.
Have you tried with a sound in the `Resources` directory?

Comment: I have, I am using the default sound just as a first step. It should work no matter what, but for some reason it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I did experience the same issue and i'm using the Ti sdk 5.2.0.GA, apparently no sound is played unless it s explicitly set for the attribute sound.

So my workaround was:

search for the default notification sound file on the internet and use it under the `app/assets/iphone` folder.

```
var notif = Ti.App.iOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
    date: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5000), // send it in 5 sec
    alertBody: 'This is your message',
    sound: '/default-notif.m4r'
)};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For devices running iOS 8 and later, you need to register the application to use the local notification services. Use the Titanium.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings() method to enroll the application in local notification services. Pass the method a dictionary with the types property set to an array of notification types to use.

Titanium.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT: allow the application to display an alert or banner message.
Titanium.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE: allow the application to modify the badge value in the application's icon.
Titanium.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_NONE: disable application UI notifications. The application will still be notified of the notification by the notification event.
Titanium.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND: allow the application to play a sound.

```
if (Ti.Platform.name == "iPhone OS" && parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 8) {
Ti.App.iOS.registerUserNotificationSettings({
    types: [
        Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT,
        Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND,
        Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE
    ]
});
```

}